# Did Shishak take away the ark of the covenant 1 Kings 14:26?

Tags: 1-kings

> 1 Kings 14:25 In the fifth year of King Rehoboam, Shishak king of Egypt attacked Jerusalem. 26He carried off the treasures of the temple of the Lord and the treasures of the royal palace. **He took everything**, including all the gold shields Solomon had made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Kings 14:26 talks about "everything" in the temple.  This presumably means everything of values such as the solid gold object including the gold on the door and gold shields.  It probably does NOT include the articles of furniture in the temple such as:

1. **The Ark of the Covenant** because this is still extant in the time of Josiah, Jer 3:16.  The non-canonical history, of 2 Maccabees 2:4-8 tells of the ark being hidden by Jeremiah to prevent it getting into pagan hands at the looming Babylonian conquest.
2. **The menorah** (7 branched lampstand) in Solomon's temple was actually 10 lampstands (1 Kings 7:49, 2 Chron 4:7, and according to Jer 52:19 were proably transported to Babylon.  However, 1 Macc 1;21 and 4:49 suggest that new ones may have been made.  In any case, the relief on the famous Arch of Titus shows the menorah being taken from Jerusalem after the temple was destroyed in 70 AD.

So, we cannot be sure exactly what was taken.

Comment: Just checked out 2 Mac 2:4-8. Interesting to read about the arc there. What puzzled me though was the mentioning of a tent. What kind of tent was that? It couldn’t be the original tabernacle, which was superseded by the temple, could it? Or was it just a cover for the arc that was called “tent”? If so, shouldn’t the wording have been “the arc with it’s tent”? In the text “tent” is mentioned first, and is called “the tent”?!?

Comment: @Constantthin - I take the "tent' to be the original tabernacle that was superseded by the brick and mortar temple.

Comment: Ok. Interesting.